# How to read A-B for the sets A,B?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Let A,B be sets. I wonder how to read "A-B". Speciffically, how to pronounce the operation "-"? Thank you.

Comment: $A - B$ is said 'A minus B'.

Comment: Alternatively, I personally read it aloud as "$A$ *without* $B$" or as "$A$ *setminus* $B$."

Comment: I'm quite idiosyncratic with pronouncing operators. For this I say "A kick B" or "A slash B" (referring to an alternative notation for set minus: $\setminus$).

Comment: The class of all objects that belong to A, and not belong to B.

Comment: The elements of $A$ are not in $B$.